# prove $G-e$ is $(k-1)$-edge connected.

Tags: graph-theory

if G is $k$-edge-connected graph and $e$ is an edge of $G$, prove that $G-e$ is $(k-1)$-edge-connected?

Could someone help me this question?

My thought is suppose there is a set $E$ of $k-2$ edges such that $G-e-E$ is disconnected, but I don't know how to the rest.

how about the vertex version of this problem, if $G$ is $k$-connected graph, prove that $G-e$ is $k-1$ connected?

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

What would it mean if $G-\{e\}$ is *not* $(k-1)$-edge-connected?  You correctly note that it should mean that there is a collection of (at most) $k-2$ edges, we label as $E$, that disconnect $G-\{e\}$.  (I.e. $((G-\{e\})-E)$ is disconnected).

What does that say about $G$ then?  If you remove those $k-2$ edges as well as $e$ what happens to the graph?

What does that mean about the edge-connectivity of $G$ in the first place?  (We noted that $((G-\{e\})-E)$ is disconnected earlier, so what about $(G-(\{e\}\cup E))$)

To explain why we choose to approach the problem this way, remember that $P\Rightarrow Q$ is logically equivalent to $\sim\!\! Q\Rightarrow \sim\!\! P$.  In otherwords, we try to show that if $G-\{e\}$ is not $(k-1)$ edge connected, then it is impossible for $G$ to be $k$ edge connected.

The vertex connectivity proof is essentially identical.

Comment: So if we remove k-2 edges and e, then we remove k-3 edges total, then G cannot be k-edge connect,which leads to contradiction??

Comment: @ZHJ Your arithmetic is off but you have the right idea.,  $k-2 + 1 = k-1 \neq k-3$, but otherwise yes.  That is the idea.  Since $(G-\{e\})-E$ is disconnected, and $(G-\{e\})-E = G-(\{e\}\cup E)$, you have a collection $\{e\}\cup E$ of $1+(k-2)=k-1$ edges which disconnects $G$, which means that it is *not* $k$-edge connected.

Comment: Could you help me with the vertex version? If we remove a set V with k-2 vertices, then how to lead contradiction?

Comment: It is literally the exact same proof, just replacing the word edge wherever it appears with the word vertex (or edges with vertices respectively).